# How i can click on iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to click Multiple times on the `iframe` designed below, though I am able to get only one alert as single click is allowed.

How can I get continuous alerts by continuous clicking.

```js
var adsappend = '<ins><ins><ins><iframe></iframe></ins></ins></ins>'
$('#ads').append(adsappend)

const listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  if (document.activeElement === iframe) {
    console.log('iframe has been clicked!');
  }
  removeEventListener('blur', listener);
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ads"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this solution is not working with nested iframe

Comment: I used google AdSense and this iframe inside of <ins> nested tags.

var adsappend = '<ins><ins><ins><iframe></iframe></ins></ins></ins>'